# Interpolating between Functions

Tags: java, math, interpolation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interpolation over an array (or two)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221944/interpolation-over-an-array-or-two)

I have a set of CSV files that contain points of a 2D function... in other words I have four CSV files, each is the result of evaluating a function f(x, y) at different y values. I need to interpolate between these data such that I can calculate an arbitrary f for a certain x and y. The CSV files have varying lengths and x-values. Does anyone know of a library or algorithm  in Java for this task? Linear interpolation is OK, as is spline interpolation.

Thanks,
taktoa

Comment: So these represent evaluations such that f(x,y) = (u,v)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all I assume the "CSV" bit is irrelevant, let's assume you have read those into memory and merged them together (they're the values of the same function, right?). Now you have a single set of `f(x,y)` values for different `(x,y)` pairs and would like to interpolate between those. Fine so far?

If you stick to linear interpolation, there's still the question of how many points to take into account, which will depend on the level of noise in the measurements. In the simplest case one would use just the three nearest points to identify the plane they lie in and use that to find the value for the point in question. This option requires neither libraries nor algorithms, apart from vector addition, subtraction, cross product and dot product.

More sophisticated solutions would generally require some sort of fitting, e.g. (weighted) [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest function is to find the closest points and use linear interpolation. e.g. chose two of three closest points and interpolate them.

Or you can take a weighted average based on distance. Or you can pick a close point and then find points on the "other side" of the closest point to improve the interpolation.

Comment: The x-values are varying between the CSV files, so there could be a significant amount of error there.

Comment: Oh are you saying I should effectively average together the x and y values between each adjacent CSV file and repeat until I have enough resolution?

Comment: My work day is over so I'm going to sign out. I'll be able to respond to any further questions at 10:00 AM EST tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the shape of the topology as to how many points you should include.

Comment: If the `x` value are unique, you can try find the x before and after and interpolate based on distance.

Answer (score 0):

[Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) would be simple and accurate.