# Java: Reduce array to specific number of averages

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, interpolation

The main issue which needs to be solved is:

Let's say I have an array with 8 numbers, e.g. [2,4,8,3,5,4,9,2] and I use them as values for my x axis in an coordinate system to draw a line. But I can only display 3 of this points. 
What I need to do now is do reduce the number of points (8) to 3, without manipulating the line too much - so using an average should be an option.
I am NOT looking for the average of the array in a whole - I still need 3 points of the amount of 8 in total.

For an array like [2,4,2,4,2,4,2,4] and 4 numbers out of that array, I could simply use the average "3" of each pair - but that's not possible if the number is uneven.

But how would I do that? Do you know how this process is called in a mathematical way?

To give you some more realistic details about this issue: I have an x axis, which is 720px long and let's say I get 1000 points. Now I have to reduce this 1000 points (2 arrays, one for x and one for y values) to a maximum of 720 points.

Thought about interpolation and stuff like that, but I'm still not quite sure if this is what I am looking for.

Comment: search term: "representative sample". Although 720 out of a population of 1000 is unusual. Just pick them at random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation is good idea. You input your points and get a polynomial function as an output. Then you can use it to draw your line. Check more here : [Interpolation over an array (or two)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221944/interpolation-over-an-array-or-two)

Comment: I have to ask this dumb question: Using the library mentioned in your linked post (Apache Commons Math) gives me a polynomial function as an output. Now I can use this function to calculate points of my line - but than I have still 1000 Points and don't know how to choose 720 of them for the polynomial function, right? I might misunderstand all of this math stuff...

Comment: You have a polynomial function f that interpolates 1000 points.Now you need 720 x's in order to get your y's using simply this: y = f(x). You can produce your x's like a linearly spaced vector or something similar.

Comment: I got my function and a linearly spaced vector for my x values. Obviously x values are not allowed getting bigger than the biggest knot point of the function. But my line has to go beyond that. So how to get y values for x values bigger than that? Thanks for your time and being patient ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if i get you. You had initially 1000 points.The smallest x and the biggest x define the area you want to draw your line right?. Can't you get the 720 y points using your function in this area?

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a more advanced mathematical function than a simple average.

I would suggest trying to identify potential algorithms via [Mathematica Stack Exchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) and then trying to find a Java library that implements any of the potential choices (maybe a new question here).

Comment: Please make sure that your answers try to answer OPs questions rather than a general advice. Comments are more suitable for  general advices.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you fit all the points you have in some fashion and then evaluate at the particular points you need for the display.

There are a myriad of choices for fitting:

1. Least squares
2. Piecewise using polynomials or splines

You should consult a text or find a library to help you - something like [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fitting.html).

Answer (score 0):

since its for an X-axis, why not use the

```
MIN, MAX and (MIN+MAX)/2
```

for your three points?

Comment: i might have misunderstood the question, but if you're talking about 8 points then interpolation would need the (x,y) and not just the x