# javascript interpolation of List(arrays)

Tags: javascript, grid, interpolation

Before I start, please accept my apologies that I'm a starter developer.

What I want is a grid with data. Only I have a list of an array with 7 points (x, y, value). I want to do this in a grid of 5x5. Only I miss a lot of values. I want to generate the missing values with help  of an interpolation function. An algorithm to search through multi-dimension (x, y) to generate a value for the other grids.

Grid example:

[image]

Grid after first generation: 4/6 surrounding fields to generate the data:
Note: blue is the 4 grid section, red is generated data

[image]

again the same algorithm to fill the whole grid

List array:

```
var listArray = [dataPoint]

    var dataPoint = { 
      x: 0, // x coordinate
      y: 0, // y coordinate
      value: 18// the value at datapoint(x, y)
    };
```

Example function

```
    var interpolation = function (listArray, gridHeight, gridWidth) {
  // function to generate missing values and matching the grid (5 by 5)
};
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show us the above grid with interpolated values?

Comment: @georg i have included the interpolated grid

Comment: @Knu8 used simple interpolation functions(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221944/interpolation-over-an-array-or-two), but not for javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested approach for getting the missing values. In this case, I search for elements which have the value `undefined` and count the values around which have a value not `undefined`.

If the actual `maxCount` matches the `count` of the adjacent values, the geometrical mean is assigned to the actual cell.

If no more value has changed, `maxCount` is increased until all sides of a cell are used to calculate the value in the middle.

Basically it works with searching for two adjacent values, then three until four values.

```js
var data = [[18, undefined, undefined, 35, undefined], [undefined, 20, undefined, undefined, 29], [undefined, undefined, undefined, 30, undefined], [undefined, 25, undefined, undefined, undefined], [undefined, undefined, 28, undefined, undefined]],
    adjacent = [{ i: -1, j: 0 }, { i: 1, j: 0 }, { i: 0, j: -1 }, { i: 0, j: 1 }],
    loop,
    minCount = 2;

do {
    loop = data.some(function (a, i) {
        return a.some(function (b, j) {
            if (b !== undefined) { return false; }
            var count = 0,
                sum = adjacent.reduce(function (s, offset) {
                    var v = (data[i + offset.i] || [])[[j + offset.j]];
                    return v === undefined ? s : (count++, s + v);
                }, 0);
            if (count === minCount) {
                data[i][j] = sum / count;
                minCount = 2;
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    if (!loop && minCount < 4) {
        minCount++;
        loop = true;
    }
} while (loop);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: sorry, i do not speak c#.

Comment: :). the array data must be passed horizontally (18-0-0-35-0 etc.).But can it pass it vertically to? (in my case 18-19-0-0-0)

Comment: pick an [earlier version](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39640632/revisions) and exchange `i` and `j`. but different search scheme is a difficult problem, like first get all edges and the the rest fromoutside to inside.