# How to get FFMPEG to show 100% finished in Java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg

```
            public void run() {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(process.getErrorStream());
                
                Pattern durPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Duration: )[^,]*");
                String dur = sc.findWithinHorizon(durPattern, 0);
                if (dur == null)
                  throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse duration.");
                String[] hms = dur.split(":");
                double totalSecs = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]) * 3600
                                 + Integer.parseInt(hms[1]) *   60
                                 + Double.parseDouble(hms[2]);
                System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalSecs + " seconds.");

                Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=time=)[^ ]*");
                String match;
                String[] matchSplit;
                while (null != (match = sc.findWithinHorizon(timePattern, 0))) {
                    matchSplit = match.split(":");
                    int hour = Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[0]) * 3600;
                    int minute = Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[1]) * 60;
                    double second = Double.parseDouble(matchSplit[2]);
                    double progress = (hour + minute + second) / totalSecs;
                    System.out.printf("Progress: %.2f%%%n", progress * 100);
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Output:

```
Total duration: 9.94 seconds.
Progress: 3.72%
Progress: 33.10%
Progress: 51.11%
Progress: 64.89%
Progress: 80.08%
Progress: 98.99%
Progress: 99.50%
```

Looking at the CLI, sometimes the progress duration will never hit the total duration so the percentage will never hit 100%. The only way I can see it reaching 100% is if we hardcode it in, like when it reaches 99.50+% then just print 100% but what if the speed is only going up by 0.01% every second? Can't think of any consistent way of achieving this. Thoughts?

Comment: In general I think hard coding a final print statement after it completes is correct. To fine tune that, what about taking the progress values to date as an array and then interpolating forward to see when you expect to be at 100%? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221944/interpolation-over-an-array-or-two