# How to get interpolation values between two list values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, math, interpolation

I have two different list values i want get the corresponding one list between value to other list between values. Please look at the list below. Here i have 1st list value of 11 and 15  here i need to find  the between  values of  12, 13 and 15.

11 value =22
15 value =30

```
List<double> list1 =[11, 15];
List<double> list2 =[22, 30];
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with dart / flutter (there is no built in function for that), it is a pure math

Comment: @pskink if you know any logic could you please provide?

Comment: Could you add the how final list should look? Because from description I don't fully understand what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/MathUtils.java#217

Comment: @powerman23rus something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221944/interpolation-over-an-array-or-two in dart

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you need the interpolation function to generate values between 2 points:

```
 List<double> interpolate(double start, double end, int count) {
  if (count < 2) {
    throw Exception("interpolate: illegal count!");
  }
  final array = List.generate(count + 1, (index) => 0.0);
  for (int i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
    array[i] = start + i * (end - start) / count;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Usage:

```
 void main() {
  final input = [1.0, 15.0];

  print(interpolate(input.first, input.last, 4));
}
```

Result:

```
[1.0, 4.5, 8.0, 11.5, 15.0]
```

Comment: Can you give me a formula for 4 values?